# Japenese character in a filename changes to garbage if I download file from IE 11

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-11

If I download a file which has Japanese character as its file name, so it gets to some garbage language in IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, here it is, I used `UrlEncode` on the filename which helped me solve my problem.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(docFileDTO.FileName)));
```